# How to read data from stdin mutiple times in C program

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a program in C to solve a maze game. The input maze file will be read from stdin. I have written below program which read the maze from stdin and prints no. of rows and columns. But once I read my input file completely how can I access it again so that I can perform the next steps?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE (1000)


struct maze {
    char ** map;
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows;
    int initdir;
};

void ReadMaze(char * filename, struct maze * maze);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct maze maze;


    ReadMaze(argv[1], &maze);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


/*  Creates a maze from a file  */

void ReadMaze(char * filename, struct maze * maze) {
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char mazeValue [BUFFERSIZE][BUFFERSIZE];
    char ** map;
    int rows = 0, foundentrance = 0, foundexit = 0;
    int columns = 0;

    /*  Determine number of rows in maze  */


    while ( fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) ){
       ++rows;
       puts(buffer);
       columns = strlen(buffer);

    }

    printf("No of rows:  %d\n", rows);
    printf("No of columns: %d\n", columns);

    if ( !(map = malloc(rows * sizeof *map)) ) {
        fputs("Couldn't allocate memory for map\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you change the format of the file to start with two values (width and height) for the size of the maze, followed by the maze data ? That way, you only need one pass on the file.

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to store that in a buffer as you read it. Once you've read `stdin`, you can't rewind it and/or read it again.

Comment: Angew can you please help me to understand how to store the data into buffer.

Comment: my maze file is like <br/>#.#######<br/>
#.......#<br/>
####.####<br/>
#....#..#<br/>
#.####.## <br/> No space in between

Comment: I would just dump it directly in a char * buffer. Sorry, my C is a little rusty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file again, [`rewind`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) can be used.

```
FILE * fp;

// Open and read the file

rewind(fp);

// Read it again

fclose(fp);
```

But, with `stdin`, this doesn't work. You must store the contents read from `stdin`.